# sublime text: How to change shortcut of autopep8?

Tags: sublimetext3, pep8

how to change the shortcut of auto pep8 in sublime text so it formats the code when i save it.

```
Default.sublime-keymap
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+8"], "command": "auto_pep8", "args": {"preview": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+8"], "command": "auto_pep8", "args": {"preview": false} }
]
```

currently i have to press ctrl+shift+8 i want to change it to ctrl+s but when i try to change it doesn't change. This file is not being edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select **`Preferences → Key Bindings`**, which opens a new window with the system default keybindings on the left and the user keybindings on the right. Copy the keybindings from the plugin's `.sublime-keymap` file into the user file on the right, then alter them as you'd like. Hit save, and they'll be activated.

In this specific case, with your wanting to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, which by default is the "Save" key combo, you should add a context to the keybinding so that it only runs AutoPEP8 on Python files:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+s"], 
  "command": "auto_pep8", 
  "args": {"preview": false},
  "context": {"key": "selector", 
              "operator": "equal", 
              "operand": "source.python", 
              "match_all": true}
}
```

Comment: @JackRyandal sorry, that was a typo